# How to enter file path in open file

Tags: 16.04, files

I want to deploy a war file, to my tomcat manage, and the path is quite long, so I want to enter the path, but whenever I go into `open file`, I can only select the files manually, by going through the folder. Is there a way to enter the file path, I have attached a picture to show the UI I get 
(BTW I'm using 16.04)

[image: here is the picture]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the open file dialog will allow you to edit the path.

I normally have a file browser in the destination folder. I use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

to copy the path. Then, in the open file dialog,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

to paste it. Finally

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

So the open file dialog goes to that folder.